# First boot after installing with DVD - Flashing white underscore

Tags: system-installation

I just installed Ubuntu from DVD, overwriting my previous Win7/Ubuntu dual boot.

Now, the first time booting Ubuntu, it is just a flashing white underscore in the top left.

I tried holding/pressing shift when booting to change to nomodeset but holding and tapping shift does nothing.

I also attempted putting the DVD in, changing nomodeset and then "Boot to local hard disk",

I got the same flashing white underscore again.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: When you reinstalled did you install grub again?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. I don't have that much experience with Ubuntu/linux in general, I just burnt ISO to disk and installed.

Answer (score 0):

The system almost certainly had grub on it before when you could boot either Ubuntu or Windows.

After repartitioning your disk you need to still use a boot loader like grub to start up the Ubuntu Linux kernel. There should be a checkmark for it in the install (if I recall correctly) and you should be able to confirm that it will be installed on the final install confirmation screen.

I'd suggest that you reinstall and make sure that you are asking for grub to be installed. It will add software to your new Ubuntu system, add the boot loader to the beginning of your disk.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar (if not the same) issue; after installing Ubuntu 12.04 by replacing a pre-installed Linux distribution I couldn't get past the black screen with a blinking / flashing underscore. I'm pretty sure I got rid of the grub bootloader somehow. Here is how I managed:

1) insert the Ubuntu image (CD or USB) again and attempt reinstalling
2) follow the partition instructions on this website at the screen Allocating Drive Space http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/04/manual-disk-partitioning-guide-for-ubuntu-11-04/
and pay attention to the last paragraph (where to install the bootloader).

Probably pretty obvious to the pro's :)